# Styling within a ng-repeat of a multi-dimensional array

Tags: angularjs, multidimensional-array, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have the following code. I can pass this a 2 dimensional array and it will display the rows independent of the size of the array

```
<div body-height class="flex-table_body horizontal-scroll flex-table_body--global-search" >
<div class="flex-table_row" ng-repeat="row in records">
    <div class="flex-table_cell flex-table_col2" ng-repeat="item in row track by $index">
        {{item}}
    </div>
</div>
```

I now want to not display the first field in the array and if it is of a certain value, apply a different style to the row

Any ideas?

Comment: you can use ng-if to check if index = 0, if so apply style="display:none" and then check its value to apply different style for those types of row

Comment: How can you apply the style to the whole row when you are in the context of a single cell?

Comment: Get its parent element, that would be the row item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I always new the first column would contain the data I needed I ended up with the following markup

```
<div body-height class="flex-table_body horizontal-scroll flex-table_body--global-search">
<div class="flex-table_row" ng-class="{'danger': row[0] === 'error', 'warning': row[0] === 'warning'}" }" ng-repeat="row in records">
    <div class="flex-table_cell flex-table_col2" ng-repeat="item in row track by $index"
         ng-class="{ 'hideColumn': $index === 0 }">
        {{item}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the row style based on the first row column value then:

**In your view:**

```
  <div body-height class="flex-table_body horizontal-scroll flex-table_body--global-search">
    <div class="flex-table_row" 
         ng-repeat="row in records" 
         ng-class="{ 'yourClass': checkFirstCol(row) }">
      <div class="flex-table_cell flex-table_col2" 
           ng-repeat="item in row track by $index">
        {{item}}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**In your controller:**

```
$scope.checkFirstCol = function(row) {
    var firstColumn = row[0];
    var wantedValue = 'Your Value';
    if(undefined !== firstColumn && null !== firstColumn) {
        return wantedValue == firstColumn;
    }
    return false;
};
```

Comment: I can see this you could apply a style here to hide the first column, but how would you apply a style to the whole row when the first column is a certain value?

Comment: you can also check for the specific value using ng-class  for eg:-                                          ng-class="{ 'yourClass': item.name == ''your value" }"

Comment: Thanks for your input, but the "item" is actually a field not a row so there is not item.name. This is the context of a field not a row. I need to apply a class to the whole row from within the context of a field.

Comment: @RichardWatts I've edited, see if this serves you well.